# finding words consisting of both letters and numerals values from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to find words consisting of both letters and numerals values of a different length in a string

```
   d = ["his car number is ka99ap9999", "bike that met with accident is kl8ar888"]
```

I want to take words consisting of both letters and numerals values from d.

and output to be like this

```
   ka99ap9999, kl8ar888
```

If answer is already available, please provide me the link, Thanks

Comment: And `'car'` is not an alphanumeric value?

Comment: No car is not alphanumeric

Comment: Are they always at the end of a string?

Comment: @Chai please have a look at the definition of alphanumeric.

Comment: @splash58 no they are not always at the end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Willem Van Onsem, '**car**' is also alphanumeric.

To get `ka99ap9999` as output, first check  every word is alphanumeric and then check it is not alphabetic and digit only.

```
d = ["his car number is ka99ap9999", "bike that met with accident is kl8ar888"]

for i in d:
    for x in i.split(' '):
        if x.isalnum() and not x.isalpha() and not x.isdigit():
            print x
```

Code :

```
python C:/Users/punddin/PycharmProjects/demo/demo.py
ka99ap9999
kl8ar888
```

Comment: That's nice, too. But you should adapt your description to also mention the "not digit only" check.

Comment: @tobias_k - Updated  !!! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for words where `any` character `isdigit` `and` `any` character `isalpha`. Just put that in a list comprehension and you are done:

```
>>> d = ["his car number is ka99ap9999", "bike that met with accident is kl8ar888"]
>>> [w for s in d for w in s.split() if any(c.isalpha() for c in w) and any(c.isdigit() for c in w)]
['ka99ap9999', 'kl8ar888']
```

Comment: This way also works: `[w for w in " ".join(d).split() if any(c.isalpha() for c in w) and any(c.isdigit() for c in w)]`